# Prevent Export/Save As of Vector Layers/Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, vector

I have created a database using postgreSQL and created multiple users assigned with different roles

Some of the users can only select and view the data and not update or delete any record. It works perfectly both in postgres and QGIS environment. However, the user can easily export the table into a shapefile in QGIS and then edit or update whatever he wants to do with the exported shapefile.

Wondering if there is a way I can lock the shapefile/table so that user cant save or export the postgis table to a shapefile in QGIS? I read something about disabling the SAVEAS button in QGIS Registry, but is this the only possible way?

Comment: may be look at WMS layers so they can only view them

Comment: But u wont be able to perform queries on WMS layers right?

Comment: if they can see the data they can copy it - there is no middle ground